# How to upload an image more than 2MB via my API

Tags: php, api, laravel-4

I'm developing an API using Laravel 4.2. Using Postman to test my methods.

Uploading image via API could not get any response due to size.

When I uploaded an image.icon it return successfully.

But when I do image.jpg (size: 2MB) it return:
`Could not get any response`

There was no code like 400, 401, etc.

PHP info:

```
max_execution_time          10000
max_file_uploads:           20
max_input_nesting_level:    64
max_input_time:             60
max_input_vars:             1000
memory_limit:               1024M
post_max_size:              5000M
upload_max_filesize         5000M
```

Code:

`$attachment = Input::file('attachment');`

How to upload an image that is more than 2MB?

**.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    php_value post_max_size 200M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 200M

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    LimitRequestBody 102400

</IfModule>
```

**Screenshots:**
[image]

Comment: are you using nginx or Apache ? if its nginx you need to make sure that nginx can handle the amount of uploaded data you send .

Comment: @zaherg im using amazon ec2 linux, apache. `Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) OpenSSL/1.0.1k-fips PHP/5.6.14`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your PHP settings to allow for larger uploads. PHP has limits on these for a number of things. POST size, upload size etc.

**NOTE**: `post_max_size` should be larger than `upload_max_filesize`.

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 125M

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 100M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

**Via .Htaccess**

You can also increase upload limit by .htaccess file:-

Write this lines after `RewriteEngine on`

```
php_value post_max_size 200M
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
```

**In your case**,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    php_value post_max_size 200M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 200M

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    LimitRequestBody 102400

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Just Write above lines after RewriteEngine on

Comment: Do you have .htaccess file in your project?

Comment: Yes. its in my project folder: `app_name/.htaccess`. I also did: `sudo service httpd restart` but still not uploading i refreshed my `website.com/phpinfo.php` its still 5000M

Comment: try to run sudo service apache2 restart and are you still facing 2MB issue? Because you told that you saw 5000M in phpinfo.

Comment: I also did try upload.  Still not uploading.

Comment: The error, I attached an image to my question, I updated it. Check it.

Comment: I found the error, it was the `LimitRequestBody` I removed it, its working now, but why? LimitRequestBody is for unlimited request to my API right? to avoid high load request of multiple users at the same time, correcT?

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini file. You can edit your php.ini settings to

```
upload_max_filesize = 8M 
post_max_size = 8M
```

Or you can use

`ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '8M');`

Comment: what about htaccess? how do I do it in htaccess?

Comment: you can write "php_value upload_max_filesize 30M"

Comment: still not uploading... check my new edit `.htaccess`